# Change the Background color of a Toglebutton when pressed in GTK3 (C language)

Tags: c, gtk3

[image]

I managed to change the background of a Button (toggle button in this case) using CSS, but I can't figure out how to keep the pressed button to hold its color.

Now the color of the Button is Blue and if you click and hold the button, the button become green.

But I need to keep the color of the Button to be Green until I press again that Button to become Blue again.

Here is the Code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void myStyleCss(void);
void createWind(GtkWidget **window, gint width, gint height);
void createGrid(GtkWidget **grid, GtkWidget **window, const gchar *name);

void chngBkgrd(gpointer *data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *button;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    myStyleCss();
    createWind(&window, 350, 250);
    createGrid(&grid, &window, "myGrid");

    button = gtk_toggle_button_new_with_label("tgl_btn");
    g_signal_connect (button, "toggled", G_CALLBACK(chngBkgrd),(gpointer *)button);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 0 , 0, 1, 1);


    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}

void myStyleCss(void){
    GtkCssProvider *provider;
    GdkDisplay *display;
    GdkScreen *screen;

    provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    display = gdk_display_get_default ();
    screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen,
                                               GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
                                               GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

    const gchar *myCssFile = "mystyle.css";
    GError *error = 0;

    gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(provider,
                                    g_file_new_for_path(myCssFile), &error);
                                    g_object_unref (provider);
}

void createWind(GtkWidget **window, gint width, gint height){
    *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(*window), "MyApp");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(*window), width, height);
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(*window), TRUE);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(*window), 5);
    g_signal_connect(*window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
}

void createGrid(GtkWidget **grid, GtkWidget **window, const gchar *name){
    *grid = gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(*grid), TRUE);
    gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(*grid), TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_name(*grid, name);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER (*grid), 50);
    g_object_set (*grid, "margin", 0, NULL);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (*window), *grid);
}

void chngBkgrd(gpointer *data){
    if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(data))){
        g_print("On\n");
    }else{
        g_print("Off\n");
    }
}
```

And here is the CSS file (mystyle.css):

```
GtkWindow {
    background-color: #A4A4A4;
    color: cyan;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: blue;
}

#myGrid {
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: grey;
}

#myChild {
    background-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: grey;
}

#tgl_btn{
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}


GtkButton {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: blue;
}

GtkButton:active {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure out how to do it, after I read somewhere the following

- :active - was used until GTK 3.16; equivalent to the :pressed class
     used when pressed upon"

The solution is to use **:checked**:

```
GtkButton:checked{
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```